# How to ignore EntityValidationErrors on ServerSide

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

Model Code:

```
public partial class Content
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public string ContentText1 { get; set; }
}
```

The view doesn't contain any Field related to Content.

Server side code on save (Controller Code):

```
Content c = new Model.Content();
db.Contents.Add(c);
db.Entry(pc).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;                
db.SaveChanges();
```

This results in an error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Is it possible to prevent this error without changing the model?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just remove the required attribute if you don't want to validate that?

Comment: Its already used in multiple views. If I remove validation then I need to add validations manually in that views.

Comment: If you *add* a new `Content` object and `ContentText1` is required then it must be validated. It's a more common scenario to want to skip validation on some properties when *updating*.

Answer (score 6):

Put this statement in the constructor of the DB, the class which inherit from `DbContext`

```
base.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Comment: @DevKumar glad to help you. Please consider accept this answer if it work for you